# RewriteRule double slash issue

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

Having this regexp in my .htaccess:

```
RewriteRule ^thumbnails/([0-9]*)/([0-9]*)/(.*)$ lib/thumb.php?w=$1&h=$2&src=$3 [QSA]
```

I'm having an issue when passing an url in arguments. The regexp remove all slashes but one. Example:

```
Enter: domain.com/thumbnails/200/143/http://img.youtube.com/vi/xxxxxxx/0.jpg
Result: domain.com/lib.tuhmb.php?w=200&h=143&src=http:/img.youtube.com/vi/xxxxxxx/0.jpg
```

Note there is just one slash after http:.

Any ideas?

Thanks!

Comment: That should really be urlencoded.

Comment: I've tried, but the regex doesn't work with the urlencoded url:
domain.com/thumbnails/243/143/http%3A%2F%2Fimg.youtube.com%2Fvi%2xxxxxxx%2F0.jpg

Comment: What do you mean it doesn't work? The `(.*)` should match _anything_, but apache is collapsing the `//` into `/` because it doesn't expect `http://` there unencoded.

Comment: Look at the result url, it gives me a bad request from apache

Comment: Sorry, i make a mistake. The url looks like:
domain.com/thumbnails/243/143/http%3A%2F%2Fimg.youtube.com%2Fvi%2Fxxxxxxx%2F0.jpg

And it just say url not found.. so i understand that the regex is not catching it...

Comment: Post your complete .htaccess. You don't have `[L]` on that rule, so it could be matched earlier or later...

Comment: Nothing else..

Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^thumbnails/([0-9]*)/([0-9]*)/(.*)$ lib/thumb.php?w=$1&h=$2&src=$3 [QSA]

Comment: Are you certain that the .htaccess is parsed at all? At the server level, if `AllowOverride` isn't defined in httpd.conf, .htaccess won't even be seen. Verify that at least a simpler pattern is rewritten. For example, just `RewriteRule ^thumbnails/([0-9]+)$ lib/thumb.php?w=$1 [L]`  Given simpler input like `/thumbnails/123` does that rewrite?

Comment: Yes.  The rule is working with no url encoded urls. For example relative urls works fine

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That is an **expected behavior** in `mod_rewrite` since rewrite engine strips multiple `/` into single `/` while applying pattern in `RewriteRule`.

To overcome this behavior use `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}` to capture your values like this:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/thumbnails/(\d+)/(\d+)/(.*)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ lib/thumb.php?w=%1&h=%2&src=%3 [L,QSA]
```